# How to check image url is 404 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Use Case:

1. when src is not null and alt tag is not null then show image of src.
2. then check src image url is not 404.
3. when src is null and alt is not null the show image of first name.
4. when src and alt are null then show default image

**HTML:**

```
<img class="imagelazy" id="lazyimage" src="http://url" alt="ankit">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function imagelazy() {

    $(document).ready(function()

        {
            var image = $(".imagelazy").attr('src');
            var altdata = $(".imagelazy").attr('alt');
            var alt = $(".imagelazy").attr('alt').split("");
            //var imagepath="http://im.gifbt.com/userimages/"+alt[0].toLowerCase()+".jpg";
            var defaultimage = "http://im.gifbt.com/img/no-pic.jpg";
            console.log(image);
            console.log(alt);
            $(".imagelazy img")
                .error(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                })
                .attr("src", defaultimage);

            if (image != '' && altdata != '') {
                console.log("afeef");
                $('.imagelazy').bind('error', function() {
                    $(this).attr("src", defaultimage);
                });
                $(".imagelazy img")
                    .error(function() {
                        $(this).hide();
                    })
                    .attr("src", defaultimage);


            } else if (image == '' && altdata != '') {
                $.each($('.imagelazy'), function(index, value) {
                    var alt1 = $(this).attr('alt').split("");
                    console.log(alt1);
                    if (alt1 != '') {
                        var imagepath1 = "http://im.gifbt.com/userimages/" + alt1[0].toLowerCase() + ".jpg";
                    }
                    console.log(this.outerHTML);
                    console.log(imagepath1);
                    $(this).attr("src", imagepath1);
                });


            } else if (altdata == '' && image == '') {
                $.each($('.imagelazy'), function(index, value) {
                    $(this).attr("src", defaultimage);
                    console.log(this.outerHTML);
                });
            }

        });
}
```

**Problem**

- Script is not working when scrolling down the page.
- When the image is set in src and alt tag is set then also first name image is displayed.
- `onerror` is not working in js.
- i have googled a lot coudln"t found the solution for this issue.
- i have found lazy.min.js js which set src="" and data-src="pathimage"
  would handled this issue.
- our requirement is optimize html that why im searching for alternate solution through js.
- i have found jquery link : https://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: `$(".imagelazy img")` doesn't seem right. Shouldn't it be `$("img.imagelazy")`? Additionally, seems like you should be iterating `$.each($('.imagelazy')` once in the main loop and reading `image`, `altdata`, etc. at that stage

Comment: @afeef you might having some other issue coz onerror always work it's written properly

Comment: onerror wouldnot  works himesh

Answer (score 20):

jQuery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
    }
});
```

Javascript:

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

Image check:

```
function ImageExist(url) 
{
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = url;
   return img.height != 0;
}
```

Other:

```
$.get(url)
    .done(function() { 
        // exists code 
    }).fail(function() { 
        // not exists code
    })
```

HTML:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="imgError()" />

function imgError()
{
alert('The image could not be loaded.');
}
```

Comment: i need to optmize html there cn give code that would help me in js

Comment: This works well, but I noticed that it returns true for empty strings too... likely interpreted as a relative link to "nothing" anchor, so no errors...

Answer (score 1):

Use `onerror` event of HTML `img` tag for 2,3 and 4th scenerio. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

```
<img src="invalid_link" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';" alt="">
```

Comment: i have optimize html so that i cannot rewrite onerror on page

Answer (score 0):

isn't this selector is wrong:

```
$(".imagelazy img")
```

This should be either:

```
$("img.imagelazy")
```

or just image class name:

```
$(".imagelazy")
```

---

And also you don't have to wrap the doc ready block in any function block. and you can optimize your code like:

```
$('.imagelazy').attr('src', function() {
    var alt1 = $(this).attr('alt').split("");
    if (alt1 != '') {
       var imagepath1 = "http://im.gifbt.com/userimages/" + alt1[0].toLowerCase() + ".jpg";
    }

    return imagepath1;
});
```

Comment: When i add ur code, i got the below error **"from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."**